# F# Compiler warning

Tags: f#

I have a simple pattern matching expression in an fsharp function that keeps generating a compiler warning and I would like to know what is causing this and what I need to do to prevent it.

In my simplified example I am trying to extract the second group of a regular expression match and then use pattern matching to either return None if the expression cannot be matched or Some(SecondGroupValue) if there is a match.

```
let GetGroup2 s = 
    let pattern = @"(d+)(.+)(d+)"
    let m : Match = Regex.Match(s, pattern) 

    // this generates a warning :
    match m.Success with 
    | true -> 
        if (m.Groups.Count >= 3) then (string)m.Groups.[2] |> Some  else  None
    | false -> None
```

The warning I am getting is:

> This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'string option'. Use ignore to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.

This function is **meant** to return 'string option'. What is the compiler trying to warn me about?

Comment: I copied & pasted your snippet - no warning. Are you sure the warning is coming from this particular function?

Comment: no it will not come from this - is will come from where you are using it - see you return a `string option` here - and you probably are using it somewhere without using it's value

Comment: After restarting Visual Studio the IDE stopped displaying the warning. My apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting Visual Studio and my computer, the IDE stopped displaying the warning. My apologies for wasting anyone's time.